# Can you have a cwl file with a macro that is only avaliable within another command?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

The mathtools' documentation gives an example for defining a helpful Set command (page 27 of version dated 2022/06/29):

```latex
% just to make sure it exists
\providecommand\given{}
% can be useful to refer to this outside \Set
\newcommand\SetSymbol[1][]{%
    \nonscript\:#1\vert
    \allowbreak
    \nonscript\:
    \mathopen{}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[1]\{\}{%
    \renewcommand\given{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]}
    #1
}
```

Which is used by

```latex
\[ \Set*{ x \in X \given \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+1} > 1 } \]
```

This made me question whether or not defining an appropriate shortcut in a custom .cwl file is possible, such that it validates \given only when it is within the context of a \Set commands' body.

Is this even possible?

Comment: No this is not currently possible. Is it that often that you accidentally use `\given` outside its proper context, though?

Comment: @mbert apologies for the delayed reply! No, I don’t use `\given` outside the specific context, even accidentally. It isn’t any kind of issue. I was just curious as to whether this was something that could be done simply out of curiosity and interest :)

Comment: No problem! I think the texstudio developers are hesitant to add features without very convincing use-cases, especially considering how finicky syntax highlighting tends to be

Comment: Oh yeah, that is entirely understandable. There is no point in implementing a standard or an obscure feature unless a large enough crowd wants the feature.